# SaveFileDialog bug in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

I'm using `Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog` class to save my files. When I saved file, and minimize my app, I can't restore it back. It happens only after when used `Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog`. Here is code:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", ev["b"], ev["a"], ev["c"]);
dlg.DefaultExt = ".csv";
dlg.Filter = "Supported format (.csv)|*.csv";
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
if (result == true)
{
    string s = dlg.FileName;
    //other code
}
```

File saves successfully, but I don't know how to solve problem with minimizing. Does anybody knows what it could be?

Comment: What is behind `//other code`?

Comment: Maybe wire up to the FileOK event and see you can catch an error there.  Just a reach.

Comment: @aleksey.berezan Writing string to file.

Answer (score 3):

WPF has all kinds of weird modality issues when you show dialogs without parent windows. I haven't seen this directly with the SaveFileDialog, but I have seen similar behavior with other dialogs. Try using the overload of .ShowDialog() where you pass in the parent window.

Comment: `Try using the overload of .ShowDialog() where you pass in the parent window.`, could be, I had same issue and solution in WinForms

Answer (score 1):

I encountered also a strange modality problem with WPF and the Win32 SaveFileDialog / OpenFileDialog.

What happens:

- The modal state is violated / gets lost completely and the main window can be clicked while the OpenFileDialog is opened with ShowDialog()

When does it happen:

- There was a task running before the OpenFileDialog opens
- The debugger breaks into a breakpoint before running the task

Just create a simple WPF Application with a button click event:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { // <-- Breakpoint sits here

        Task.Run(() => {}).Wait();

        new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog().ShowDialog();
    }
```

Using the overloaded `ShowDialog(Window owner)` function solves this problem.